# Can I extract the rootfs from a UBoot Linux image?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have prepared uImage of the kernel; now I want to unpack the root filesystem image from it.  How can I do that?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage/22338835#22338835).  What did you put in the uImage file?  Simply remove the wrapper code that was added to "get back" the original kernel image.    *"get back to normal rootfs"*  What rootfs?  What are you really trying to accomplish?.

Comment: I downloaded prebuilt uImage and i want to see the content of uImage for that I want to extract uImage.

Comment: Thanks sawdust, But I have already shown that post. and also one of script I found http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/How_to_Extract_an_uImage. But it was given me Image file which has been generic Linux kernel Image. I need more extraction on that then only I get data and still its remaining...

Comment: Hi SubliemeSiem, Actually I have never doing this stuff before so it was little bit complicated for me. there was uboot header+ zImage= uImage.I had tried above mention script.but it was just removed the uImage header and given me Image file and it was binary format.

Comment: Is there any utility or command for the read binary format file??such as objdump like that.

Comment: *"given me Image file and it was binary format"* -- Yes, an image file is a binary file.  What else did you expect?  (You're doing a poor job of replying to questions that could explain your confusion.)

Comment: It's okay, sawdust. I have tried binwalk utility and I am able to read string now.Thanks for taking your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Binwalk http://binwalk.org is cool to extract images. To automate this process I analyse image with binwalk to get offsets of contained images. After write script with `dd` or `python`. This script extracts offset fron file, after cuts to parts.