# Can a zImage be wrapper as a uImage and still boot successfully?

Tags: linux, u-boot

A uImage seems to just be a header prepended to a payload. I am working with a build of U-Boot that does not support the `bootz` command, so I am wondering if a zImage wrapped as a uImage can be loaded by U-Boot without troubles.

Comment: Yes. Possible duplicate of [Image vs zImage vs uImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage)

Answer (score 0):

That's what a uImage historically on ARM is, the kernel zImage with the required additional header applied on top.