# earlyprintk not work as expected, kernel hung during booting

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel

I am booting the kernel (arm, cortexa15), and the kernel hung at:

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 40007fc0 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.4.138-cip25-rt19-yocto-s
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    5510400 Bytes = 5.3 MiB
   Load Address: 40008000
   Entry Point:  40008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 40f00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x40f00000
   XIP Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 40ef1000, end 40effb37 ... OK

   Starting kernel ...
```

I tried to enable earlyprintk to know where the kernel stuck.

```
CONF_PRINTK=y
CONF_EARLY_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_LL=y (low-level debug)
# CONFIG_DEBUG_ICEDCC is not set
```

and set bootargs:

```
> setenv bootargs ${bootargs_base} earlyprintk
```

But, there is not message printed on console. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Earlyprintk is not going to help you in this situation because the Linux kernel has not started executing yet (despite the status message from U-Boot).  You're probably booting a zImage, which first needs to self-decompress (despite the status message from U-Boot).  You need to provide a lot more information such as your board information, U-Boot environment and full boot log.

Comment: You also need to know if your kernel is configured for silent or verbose decompression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930346/uncompressing-is-not-happening-with-zimage-while-booting-up-with-u-boot/47009714#47009714

Comment: if you can you may add a couple of leds on the gpio of board and toggle them at different places in code so that you can know where exactly you are, if that helps