# Buildroot + U-Boot + Rpi4 : Error zImage Bad Magic

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot, buildroot, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project where I want to create my own embedded linux with U-Boot. Therefore I am working with buildroot, which i recently start learning. After successfully creating my own rasberrypi4_defconfig i am currently struggling at the problem to get u-boot work correctly.

**What versions I am working with:**

1. Rpi 4
2. buildroot-2019.11
3. u-boot (therefore i pull everyday the new changes)

**Current State of the work:**

I build on a Ubuntu(32bit). I configure buildroot with the *raspberrypi4_defconfig* and make it without changes. Then i make a u-boot defconfig for *rpi_4_32b_defconfig* and create the u-boot.bin with `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- u-boot.bin`
Now my next step was to configure the config.txt and exchange the content with following:

```
enalbe_uart=1
kernel=u-boot.bin
```

In addition i copyied my u-boot.bin into my sd-card.

The last step that i actually did is to build my own boot.scr.uimg with following content

```
fatload mmc O:1 ${fdt_addr_r} bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} Image.4.8
setenv bootargs console=ttyS0, 115200 \
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw
bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
```

**Problem**
So far i am archieving to reach the U-boot menu but on booting i get the error: zimage Bad Magic
I actually thing that my boot.scr.uimg is maybe not correct but dont get it.

**Boot Log**

After calling boot following is printed:

```
    U-Boot 2020.01-rc4-00066-g7e5ee346fc (Dec 05 2019 - 16:55:27 +0100)

    DRAM:  948 MiB
    RPI 4 Model B (0xc03111)
    MMC:   emmc2@7e340000: 0, mmcnr@7e300000: 1
    Loading Environment from FAT... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

    In:    serial
    Out:   serial
    Err:   serial
    Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
    No ethernet found.
    Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
    switch to partitions #0, OK
    mmc0 is current device
    Scanning mmc 0:1...
    Found U-Boot script /boot.scr.uimg
    291 bytes read in 17 ms (16.6 KiB/s)
    ## Executing script at 02400000
    40559 bytes read in 33 ms (1.2 MiB/s)
    zimage: Bad magic!
    SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...
    40559 bytes read in 29 ms (1.3 MiB/s)
    Card did not respond to voltage select!
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: pxeuuid
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-bcm283x-rpi
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-bcm283x
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm
    No ethernet found.
    missing environment variable: bootfile
    Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default
    No ethernet found.
    Config file not found
    No ethernet found.
    No ethernet found.
```

**Environment**

```
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=rpi
board_name=4 Model B
board_rev=0x11
board_rev_scheme=1
board_revision=0xC03111
boot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}
boot_efi_binary=if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi bootmgr ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi bootmgr ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;load ${devty
pe} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${f
dt_addr_r};else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi
boot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}
boot_prefixes=/ /boot/
boot_script_dhcp=boot.scr.uimg
boot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scr
boot_syslinux_conf=extlinux/extlinux.conf
boot_targets=mmc0 mmc1 pxe dhcp
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 \
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw
bootcmd=run distro_bootcmd
bootcmd_dhcp=if dhcp ${scriptaddr} ${boot_script_dhcp}; then source ${scriptaddr}; fi;setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${f
dtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; setenv efi_old_vci ${bootp_vci};setenv efi_old_
arch ${bootp_arch};setenv bootp_vci PXEClient:Arch:00010:UNDI:003000;setenv bootp_arch 0xa;if dhcp ${kernel_addr_r}; then tftpboot $
{fdt_addr_r} dtb/${efi_fdtfile};if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r}; else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r
} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;fi;setenv bootp_vci ${efi_old_vci};setenv bootp_arch ${efi_old_arch};setenv efi_fdtfile;setenv efi_old_arch;s
etenv efi_old_vci;
bootcmd_mmc0=devnum=0; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_mmc1=devnum=1; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_pxe=dhcp; if pxe get; then pxe boot; fi
bootdelay=2
bootfstype=fat
cpu=armv7
dhcpuboot=usb start; dhcp u-boot.uimg; bootm
distro_bootcmd=for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; done
efi_dtb_prefixes=/ /dtb/ /dtb/current/
ethaddr=dc:a6:32:45:1f:d1
fdt_addr=2eff5d00
fdt_addr_r=0x02600000
fdt_high=ffffffff
fdtcontroladdr=3af6ac98
fdtfile=bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
fileaddr=2600000
filesize=9e6f
initrd_high=ffffffff
kernel_addr_r=0x00080000
load_efi_dtb=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}
loadaddr=0x00200000
mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then devtype=mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
pxefile_addr_r=0x02500000
ramdisk_addr_r=0x02700000
scan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done;run scan_dev_for_efi;
scan_dev_for_boot_part=part list ${devtype} ${devnum} -bootable devplist; env exists devplist || setenv devplist 1; for distro_bootpart in ${devplist}; do if fstype ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} bootfstype; then run scan_dev_for_boot; fi; done; setenv devplist
scan_dev_for_efi=setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; for prefix in ${efi_dtb_prefixes}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}; then run load_efi_dtb; fi;done;if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; then echo Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootarm.efi; run boot_efi_binary; echo EFI LOAD FAILED: continuing...; fi; setenv efi_fdtfile
scan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; then echo Found ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi
scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; done
scriptaddr=0x02400000
serial#=10000000f58b842c
soc=bcm283x
stderr=serial,vidconsole
stdin=serial,usbkbd
stdout=serial,vidconsole
usbethaddr=dc:a6:32:45:1f:d1
vendor=raspberrypi

Environment size: 3996/16380 bytes
```

Comment: Post the full boot log and the U-Boot environment (i.e. the `printenv` command).

Comment: @Rob why did you close that post what did i wrong ?

Comment: @sawdust i just posted the output above

Comment: The references to **bootfile** are irrelevant.  The salient error message indicates you have not installed a valid **zImage** file, but instead are trying to use (i.e. `fatload ... Image.4.8`) an **Image** file.  Names and spelling do matter!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage/22338835#22338835  BTW seems like desktop developers are inclined to close embedded development questions that resemble desktop or network admin queries.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the question you're askinng or problem you're experiencing. Simply repeating the information that is already available in the tags isn't useful. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader here who is looking through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title provides no useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far i am archieving to reach the U-boot menu but on booting i get the error: zimage Bad Magic I actually thing that my boot.scr.uimg is maybe not correct but dont get it.

That error message traces back to the contents of your **boot.scr.uimg**:

```
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} Image.4.8
...  
bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
```

The **bootz** command expects a **zImage** file at the first memory address.
But the prior **fatload** command has copied a file named **Image.4.8** into memory.
By convention an **Image** file is the generic Linux kernel binary image file, whereas a **zImage** file is a compressed version of the Linux kernel image that is self-extracting.

You need to install the **zImage** that you built (instead of the **Image** file) to the SD card.  Edit your **boot.scr.uimg** to indicate the proper file type/name.

---

**ADDENDUM**

U-Boot does have a **booti** command for the generic Linux kernel binary **Image** file, but that command is intended only for ARM64, e.g. the built-in help text is `boot arm64 Linux Image image from memory`.
See [the patch that configures that command](https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2015-March/208510.html).

Comment: sorry for conntacting you again but when changing zu zImage i am stucking now in Starting Kernel do you know what this problem could cause ?