# Booting Linux from U-Boot. Raspberry pi 3 b plus - U-Boot, bootz command not present with default config

Tags: raspberry-pi3, u-boot

I want to boot my Raspberry PI 3 B+ over TFTP from Uboot.
I built and successfully loaded U-Boot

I followed the instructions from https://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot.
I could boot the RPI in Uboot and load the zImage over TFTP.

But the last step requires the execution of the bootz command which is not present in U-boot with default config.

The following commands are available:
boot bootd bootefi bootelf booti bootm bootp bootvx

```
U-Boot version 
U-Boot 2021.01-rc2-00156-g7889951d0f
```

Is there an up-to-date instruction for raspberry pi and the latest versions of buildroot/uboot?

Comment: This question belongs on [raspberrypi.se] instead.

Comment: `bootz` is an optional command, and can be enabled using the configuration menu at `Command line interface` → `Boot commands` → `bootz`.  If you do not want to or cannot rebuilt U-Boot, you could use the **zImage** file to turn it into a **uImage** with the **mkimage** command, and then use the `bootm` command.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage

Answer (score 1):

When running a 64bit U-Boot you need to use `booti` to boot the Linux kernel "Image" file rather than `bootz` to boot the kernel "zImage".