Where is the code about jumps to kernel code section in U-Boot?
I've been studying how U-Boot gets loaded into RAM, and how it loads the kernel into RAM and then transfers control to the kernel.
First, the MLO loads the U-Boot program into RAM. Through the U-Boot prompt, the fatload command is issued to load the kernel image into RAM. Then, using the bootm or bootz command from the U-Boot prompt, control is transferred to the kernel by jumping to the entry point of the kernel image that was loaded into memory.
However, I couldn't find the code responsible for this jump, so I’m asking this question.
Personally, I think the kernel image has a header section and a code section, with the header section containing the offset of the code section’s start. When the fatload command is issued, the load address (loadaddr) is provided as a parameter or a default value is used, and from this value, the kernel code section starts at an offset.
Therefore, there should be a part of the code that calculates this entry point. But I’ve only found this entry point calculation code for AArch64, and I couldn’t find the 32-bit code.
If there is code for calculating the entry point for 32-bit systems, I’d appreciate it if you could point it out.
Thanks! :D

"First, the MLO loads the U-Boot program into RAM" - MLO is not a generic term, and is specific to just one SoC vendor. Nor does every SoC use U-Boot's SPL. "I couldn't find the code responsible for this jump" - What have you tried? Since there are U-Boot commands to instigate the kernel boot, have you inspected the code that implements those commands? During boot U-Boot issues the salient message Starting kernel ... on the console just before the jump to the kernel. Have you tried to search the U-Boot source code for that salient text string???

"If there is code for calculating the entry point ..." - You are on the wrong track. Binary executables such as the Linux kernel image file try to keep things simple. The start address of the executable is typically the first address of the image. If that were not true, then you would have to use the U-Boot header/wrapper on the image to provide U-Boot with the entry point. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage
