Can I inspect the rootfs from this QSPI dump?
I was messing around with a cheap IP camera from Amazon. The board uses an Ingenic T20, which seems to be very common for this application. I desoldered the QSPI NOR Flash and dumped it with another microcontroller. Inspecting the file with strings is very promising, and I see several U-Boot related strings, but binwalk doesn't report any files aside from one 'Android bootimg' which seemed to me like a false positive:
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
306555        0x4AD7B         Android bootimg, kernel size: 0 bytes, kernel addr: 0x70657250, ramdisk size: 543519329 bytes, ramdisk addr: 0x6E72656B, product name: "mem boot start"

For example, from strings I think I can see the kernel boot arguments among other things:
Board: ISVP (Ingenic XBurst T20 SoC)
        
U-Boot 2013.07 (Aug 12 2021 - 11:26:54)
jz_serial
console=ttyS1,115200n8 mem=100M@0x0 ispmem=8M@0x6400000 rmem=20M@0x6C00000 init=/linuxrc rootfstype=squashfs root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw mtdparts=jz_sfc:256k(boot),2048k(kernel),6752k(rootfs),6752k(app),512k(cfg),64k(para),832k(cback),2048k(kback),6752k(rback),[[way],[mmc_select],[mem_address],[sectors]]
- boot Android system....

...

ERROR: pll freq is not integer times than cpu freq or/and ddr freq
at %s:%d/%s()
ERROR: Periph pll freq %d is out of range
at %s:%d/%s()
l2cache_clk = %d
pll_cfg.pdiv = %d, pll_cfg.h2div = %d, pll_cfg.h0div = %d, pll_cfg.cdiv = %d, pll_cfg.l2div = %d

...

U-Boot
U-Boot SPL 2013.07 (Aug 12 2021 - 11:26:54)
jz_sfc_readl(SFC_SR) : %x
(null)
Cannot find console

There was also an exposed UART, and I recorded the boot process for that before desoldering. There are two more locations where I can see the MTD partition scheme:
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping off.  Total pages: 25400
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyS1,115200n8 mem=100M@0x0 ispmem=8M@0x6400000 rmem=20M@0x6C00000 init=/linuxrc rootfstype=squashfs root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw mtdparts=jz_sfc:256k(boot),2048k(kernel),6752k(rootfs),6752k(app),512k(cfg),64k(para),832k(cback),2048k(kback),6752k(rback),6752k(aback)

[    0.816297] the id code = c84019, the flash name is GD25Q256
[    0.822171] JZ SFC Controller for SFC channel 0 driver register
[    0.828370] 10 cmdlinepart partitions found on MTD device jz_sfc
[    0.834633] Creating 10 MTD partitions on "jz_sfc":
[    0.839691] 0x000000000000-0x000000040000 : "boot"
[    0.845249] 0x000000040000-0x000000240000 : "kernel"
[    0.850905] 0x000000240000-0x0000008d8000 : "rootfs"
[    0.856641] 0x0000008d8000-0x000000f70000 : "app"
[    0.862061] 0x000000f70000-0x000000ff0000 : "cfg"
[    0.867553] 0x000000ff0000-0x000001000000 : "para"
[    0.873107] 0x000001000000-0x0000010d0000 : "cback"
[    0.878704] 0x0000010d0000-0x0000012d0000 : "kback"
[    0.884381] 0x0000012d0000-0x000001968000 : "rback"
[    0.890027] 0x000001968000-0x000002000000 : "aback"
[    0.895717] SPI NOR MTD LOAD OK

Why might binwalk not find any squashfs file systems when the boot args specify the rootfs uses one? Is it possible that everything after the SPL is encrypted? I seem to only see U-Boot related strings.
My main goal is to be able to mount the rootfs and take a look around, but I'm not sure how permissions would work with something like this. What steps should I take next?

Besides the one mention in the kernel parameters, what makes you think there's a squashfs? Have you found the crucial kernel boot message Freeing init memory ... that indicates device initialization is complete, and the kernel is about to mount the rootfs? Is there any message indicating that a rootfs is actually mounted, or is there an initramfs instead? "Is it possible that everything after the SPL is encrypted?" - Correction: SPL happens before U-Boot. Did you check if the kernel is a zImage (i.e. compressed but with a self-decompression routine at the beginning of the image)?

@sawdust Yes, it seems like it does sucessfully mount the rootfs:
[    1.648806] VFS: Mounted root (squashfs filesystem) readonly on device 31:2.   [    1.656594] Freeing unused kernel memory: 236K (80545000 - 80580000)
Thank you for the correction as well, you're right about the SPL.
Here's the full dump https://pastebin.com/xGcedpKE

I'm also skeptical that the kernel is a zImage since it should have been picked up by binwalk, right?

"I'm also skeptical that the kernel is a zImage ..." - The specific boot command employed by U-Boot would confirm that. Inspect the U-Boot environment for the bootd variable. The boot log seems to indicate that the kernel image is a uImage. There would be the 64-byte uImage header followed by the (lzma compressed) kernel Image. If binwalk didn't find this, then inspect the dump manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage/22338835#22338835

The boot log indicates that the target uses a MIPS processor. So multi-byte binary values might be stored in big-endian order, whereas little-endian order is more common (e.g. on x86 and ARM). Does binwalk account for this byte ordering?

@sawdust, zImage is usually x86 stuff, ARM platforms might use uImage. Hmm... there are recent articles about usage of zImage on ARM, so I stand corrected. (FWIW, https://people.kernel.org/linusw/how-the-arm32-linux-kernel-decompresses)

If you provide a copy of the of the flash dump and/or open an issue on the Binwalk github page (https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/issues) I can take a peek at it.

thanks everyone for the help! I ended up dumping the rootfs from u-boot and I was able to unsquashfs it. Binwalk worked fine on that binary, so I believe my flash dumping code had some bugs.

In case anyone was curious, heres what the binwalk for the kernel image and rootfs looked like respectively. https://pastebin.com/raw/jZFwN6fD. I still have more work to do since it seems like the application code and configuration are on a different part of flash, but at least this is progress.
